# IP v 4 subnetting and addresses

Tags: ip-address, ipv4, subnet, cidr

Hello I am struggling working out IP address and their subnet networks. I am faced with the following question as an example I would like to know if the answers I came up with are indeed correct.

The Question is as follows
[image: Question]

And my answers to the problem.

a i) 255.255.254.0
  ii) 137.215.214.0/23
  iii) 137.215.215.255

b i) 255.255.240.0
  ii) 137.215.208.0/20
  iii) 137.215.223.255

c i) 255.255.255.240 ii) 137.215.215.208/28 iii) 137.215.215.223

Thanks for any help in advance. I am struggling to wrap me head around this since my textbook is not that great.

Comment: Sad to see that there are still exercises that are based on classful subnetting :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the prefix 137.x.x.x dictates the class of IP address class B. In general class B addresses are in format N.N.H.H/16 .
so generic netmask without subnetting is 16.
subnetting is a process by which you can borrow few host bits to accomodate more networks.
In this example you have 16 host bits.

case1:
n = 100  c= 300
to have 100 subnets 64(6bits) < 100 < 128(7bits) you will have to reserve 7 bits from left .
and for 300 hosts would need 256(8bits) < 300 < 512(9bits) ie 9 bits

so 137.x.nnnnnnnh.hhhhhhhh

that would give you,

```
IP as entered by you 137.215.215.215
mask:255.255.254.0
network IP:137.215.214.0
first host IP:137.215.214.1
last host IP:137.215.215.254
Broadcast IP:137.215.215.255
number of hosts:510
```

I think you can work out from here.